# Click and load multiple links with different GET parameters (which auto submits)

Tags: javascript, ajax, batch-processing

Currently I have a page (index.php) where user can click on a link which links to another page with GET parameters (upload.php).

**index.php**

1. Content A (Link to upload.php?id=123&name=abc)
2. Content B (Link to upload.php?id=456&name=efg)
3. Content C (Link to upload.php?id=789&name=hij)

**upload.php**

Clicking on one of the links above will get the user to upload.php which will parse the GET parameters and put it into a HTML form, and then auto submits. Thus putting the parameters into the database.

**My Question**

It is troublesome to click many times just to do this auto submit.

I wish to click on a "BATCH UPLOAD" link in index.php, and it would automatically loads the 3 links in background, and upload all the parameters into the database.

Is there any way to do this using AJAX or any better way?

Comment: You Can easily send multiple GET requests at once with jQuery AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is that what you mean ?

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks for your question. Yes it sounds like what I wish to do. Multiple GET requests at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick with jQuery, but you need to write the values directly to the database in upload.php not auto submit a form in between...

```
function batchUpload(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "upload.php?id=123&name=abc"     
    });

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "upload.php?id=456&name=efg"     
   });

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "upload.php?id=789&name=hi"     
  });

}
```

Comment: Okay great this seems like a solution. Would try it out. It's my intention to put the form submit in upload.php also. Many thanks for your great answer from the other side of the world.

Comment: Oke Just be aware that the form will be returned as a response to the Ajax request dont think that is desired. Side note: if all of your requests go to the same script you can conbime them.

Comment: Okay would only try the code tomorrow. Would take note of what you mentioned.